# Postgres returns empty table if lateral join doesnt fetch any rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run the below query everytime a user logs in to get the relevant data

```
SELECT ac.username,ac.password,
(array_agg(json_build_object('message',pm.message,'username',pm.username,'message_id',pm.message_id)))[0:10] AS messages,
p.project_name,p.project_id
FROM account ac,
LATERAL(SELECT * FROM accounts_projects WHERE ac.user_id = accounts_projects.account_id) ap,
LATERAL(SELECT * FROM project_messages WHERE ap.project_id = project_messages.project_id ORDER BY project_messages.message_id) pm,
LATERAL(SELECT * FROM project WHERE project.project_id = ap.project_id) p
WHERE ac.username=$1
GROUP BY p.project_name,p.project_id,ac.user_id;
```

Lets say i have 2 users -

user 1 has joined projects (accounts_projects table) -> he gets the below output

```
  username: 'kannaj',
  projects: 
   [ { project_name: 'Machine Learning with Python',
       messages: [Object],
       project_id: 1 },
     { project_name: 'Beethoven with react',
       messages: [Object],
       project_id: 3 },
     { project_name: 'Football with Javascript',
       messages: [Object],
       project_id: 2 } ] }
```

However , if theres a new user who doesnt belong to the accounts_projects. postgres returns an empty row. i.e just fetch ac.user_id & password based on username and null values for other columns?

Is there anyway i can get postgres to **ignore** or return null for the lateral join if there is no data found? It should ideally only fetch ac.username and ac.password.

It does look like a simple LEFT JOIN should do the trick. I tried updating the query like this

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM accounts_projects WHERE ac.user_id = accounts_projects.account_id) ap,
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM project_messages WHERE ap.project_id = project_messages.project_id ORDER BY project_messages.message_id) pm,
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM project WHERE project.project_id = ap.project_id) p
```

but i get the the below error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "JOIN"
LINE 6: LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM accounts_projects WHERE ac.u...
             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "JOIN"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 206
```

Comment: Use `left join lateral (...) on true` instead.

Comment: @Abelisto - i just updated the question  .. i did use left join .. but i'm getting a syntax error :( .. i havent tried with 'on true' yet though

Comment: yea .. turns out i dont need to use commas :/

Comment: Exactly, as with regular joins :)

Comment: thanks for you help .. i would've approved your answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 4):

As usual JOIN should to have join condition: "join < table expression > on < join condition >" To complain it is possible "ON TRUE"

Try:

```
SELECT ac.username,ac.password,
(array_agg(json_build_object('message',pm.message,'username',pm.username,'message_id',pm.message_id)))[0:10] AS messages,
p.project_name,p.project_id
FROM account ac
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM accounts_projects WHERE ac.user_id = accounts_projects.account_id) ap ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM project_messages WHERE ap.project_id = project_messages.project_id ORDER BY project_messages.message_id) pm ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT * FROM project WHERE project.project_id = ap.project_id) p ON TRUE
WHERE ac.username=$1
GROUP BY p.project_name,p.project_id,ac.user_id;
```